# Is there a QML type allowing to execute certain actions once some condition became true?

Tags: qt, properties, binding, qml, conditional-statements

I need to execute some QML slot once certain condition became true.

I know there is a Binding type which can assign a property with some value once "when" condition became true. I need something similar but instead of setting the "value" to "property" I want to execute some arbitrary actions.

Thanks.

Comment: Help refine your question by supplying what you've tried. To tailor an answer, we need some more specifics of the problem you wish to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a third party library that does that : [benlau's QuickPromise](https://github.com/benlau/quickpromise)

You could use it that way :

```
import QuickPromise 1.0
//...
Promise {
    resolveWhen: someExpression
    onFulfilled: arbitraryAction()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In other words, something like this?

```
QtObject {
    readonly property bool foobar: someExpression
    onFoobarChanged: {
         if (foobar) { ... }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use [Connections](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#using-the-connections-type) type:

```
Connections {
    target: conditionKeeper
    onConditionChanged: console.log("Processing...")
}
```

You could keep your logic in any QObject, even in C++. Once your condition becomes true, your code will be executed. It can be used out of the box without any dependencies.